# .fadeIn() on newly added element

Tags: jquery, html

Trying to dynamicly add a new hidden div on a click event, then fadein this div.

```
$('.param').on('click',function(event){
        $(this).fadeOut('slow');
        $('#bibox').append('<div style="display: none;" id="test"> Hello World!</div>');
        $('#test').fadeIn('slow');
    });
```

It add new hidden div correctly into the #bibox one, but stay hidden.

Comment: id should be unique

Comment: Actually it's the case, changed it for the test case to post here.

Comment: Please provide a reproducible example the code you provided appears to work. https://jsfiddle.net/xeqqsnsL/

Comment: The test code was not working on my end. using mariobros answer worked.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
$('.param').on('click',function(event){
    $(this).fadeOut('slow');
    var html = '<div style="display: none;" id="test"> Hello World!</div>';
    $(html).hide().appendTo("#bibox").fadeIn('slow');
});
```

Comment: Seems to work! Was it needed to hide before fadein oO?

Answer (score 2):

This is working for me:

```js
$('.param').on('click',function(event){
        $(this).fadeOut('slow');
        $('#bibox').append('<div style="display: none;" id="test"> Hello World!</div>');
        $('#test').fadeIn('slow');
    });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="param">Click me!</div>
<div id="bibox"></div>
```